# Bash script to 7za all files in a directory then rename files

Tags: regex, bash, for-loop, rename, 7zip

I am working on using 7za to compress and password protect all files in a directory then rename the files.
Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash

rename 's/ /_/g' *
rename 's/_-_/_/g' *

Password_string=My_Password_String
a=1

for i in *;
do 7za a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off -p$Password_string -mhe=on $i.7z $i
    new=$(printf "Summer_Vacat_%04d.7z" "$a") 
    mv -i -- "$i" "$new"
    let a=a+1 #increment counter
done
```

I am in the directory with all the folders I want to 7za and password protect, the `mv` command renames the folders before they are compressed. I want to rename $i.7z to Summer_Vacat_0000.7z, what am I missing here? This is only the first phase of this program...

Comment: Why rename the file rather than directly creating it with the right name?

Comment: Honestly, I pieced this together. How would you improve this?

Comment: Err you’re passing the target filename to `7za`. Just pass `$new` instead of `$i` (obviously you’d need to *first* create the filename and *then* call `7za`. Incidentally the semicolon at the end of the `for` line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

Password_string=My_Password_String
a=1

for i in *;
do
  7za a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off -p$Password_string -mhe=on $i.7z $i
  if [ -f "${i}.7z" ];then
    new=$(printf "Summer_Vacat_%04d.7z" "$a")
    mv -i "${i}.7z" "$new"
    rm -f "$i" # this will remove the unencrypted or original file
    let a=a+1 #increment counter
  fi
done
```

Note that if your script is in this folder, it will also be encrypted and renamed.. so you need to check for the name and exclude it from the loop

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark the answer as Accepted

Comment: I solved the issue with the script possibly being encrypted too by simply palcing in my /.local/bin/ directory and making it executable. Thanks.